# ExtJs Tree Show Hide Node

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, tree

Hi I want to search entire tree panel and search for certain attribute(for Ex. attr.CC) ,if it matches i want to display the childNode along with all its parents if any.

For Example

+-A
+-A1
+-B
+-B1
+-B2
+-C
+-C1
+-C2
+-C3
+-D
+-DD
+-DD1
+-DDD
+-DDD1
+-DDD2
+-DD3

(Assuming nodes ending in a number are leaf nodes)

So - If I'm at A1 <-> B1 <-> B2 <-> C1 <-> 
C2 <-> C3 <-> DD1 <-> DDD1 <-> DDD2 <-> DD3
etc..
 for example node DDD2 is matching with attribute, then  i want to display

+D
+-DD
+-DDD1
-DDD2

I want to Hide the remaining node which are not matching. Please provide a Code for the above scenario.

Comment: But then, what is your question and how did you try to find an answer?

Comment: I need to Tree traversing code for the above which will return that tree and hides the remaining node(No Deletion)

Comment: You mean you have tried to implement said code, and you now have code that is not working and only throws errors, and you would like to [show us your code so we can help](http://fiddle.sencha.com)? Or are you lacking [proper documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-method-cascadeBy) or [examples](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148380-extjs-tree-iterate-through-all-nodes)?

Comment: I have tried with  following code. this.matchedTreePanel.getRootNode().cascade(function() { 
    if(!this.attributes['CC'] == "#008000") { 
     this.getUI().show(); 
    }})  Which is hiding the respective but my problem quite opposite i want to show that and its all parent

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.